# BuildNotificationApp included in VS 2015 does not monitor

Tags: tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration, visual-studio-2015

I have VS 2015 using Win10.  The BuildNotificationApp connects to TFS 2013 and correctly shows build definitions.  But, the popup states that "This build definition will not be monitored."  These build definitions use standard ReleaseTfvcTemplate12.xaml.

What will it take to get it running?  Not having to work is a big problem as developers are unaware something is broken.  Loss of time in getting fixes.

The app is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\

Comment: I'm not sure what's broken, but I monitor builds using TFS e-mail alert notifications.

Comment: Does the same problem occur on all terminals/build definitions/users, etc?

Comment: Can you see your build result of this definition through Team Explorer in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3):

**If only this build definition can’t  be monitored.** I suggest you could first check the state of the build definition in Build Notifications Options. Open Build Notifications APP , then choose Options, select your build definition.

**Blank** means: This build definition will be monitored

□ means: You gated  check-ins affecting this build definition will be monitored

■ means: This build definition will  not be monitored.

Make sure your settings are collect, then exit your BuildNotificationApp , reopen it.
[image]

**If all of the build definition can’t be monitor.** I suggest that you could stop Build Notifications and VS, clean your Windows Temp and your User Temp directories and restart Build Notifications and VS.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  Not having checkbox means that Build Notification is being monitored.  I was expecting a checkbox with checkmark as all-is-ok for monitoring signal.  Thanks!